# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am stuck with this error since last few hours.. i dont know what am i doing wrong here..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function viewProfile(index)
    {
        var GridID = document.getElementById("PersonGridView");
        var row=GridID.rows[parseInt(index)+1];
        window.open('detailsid.aspx?'+row);
    }
    </script>
```

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField = "LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="HomePhoneNumber" DataField="HomePhoneNumber" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ViewDetails">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Deatils" runat="server" Text="Details" />
            </ItemTemplate>    

            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Modify" runat="server" Text="Modify" />
            <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>


        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<p> Code Behind : 
protected void PersonGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

               if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
         var ID = PersonGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();

                Button btnDetails = (Button)FindControl("Details");
                Button btnModify = (Button)FindControl("Modify");
                Button btnDelete = (Button)FindControl("Delete");
                btnModify.CommandName = "Modify";
                btnDelete.CommandName = "Delete";
                btnDetails.CommandName = "Details";
                btnDelete.CommandArgument = btnModify.CommandArgument = string.Format("{0}", ID);
                btnDetails.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("viewProfile({0}); return false;", ID);


            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to post the code that's causing the problem along with what you're trying to accomplish rather than dumping the error message.

Comment: i dont exactly know what is creating problem.. i am a newbie.. rather not to confuse people, i have posted whole scenario here..

Comment: My guess is that e.Row.RowIndex is either undefined or doesn't match a DataKey. You should check how your method is called to ensure that parameter is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the line that's throwing the error?:

```
var ID = PersonGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
```

This line is referencing an array item by index in two different places, so you'll need to do a little debugging to determine which one is the problem.  Basically, either `PersonGridView.DataKeys[]` doesn't have an index which matches `e.Row.RowIndex` or that item doesn't have an index which matches `"ID"`.  You'll need to either step through a debugger to examine those values at runtime or toss in some debugging code (`Response.Write` statements and such to examine values) to see what's going on.

One common error is that the `DataGridView` is running this code on non-data rows.  Header, footer, etc.  You can expand the scope of the `if` statement to address that.  Reference the indexes within the conditional rather than outside of it.

**Edit:** (In response to your comment below)

Is `btnDetails` set to an instance of an object?  I'm guessing it isn't.  You'll need to continue the debugging and see if the control you're trying to find is actually there.  I notice that it's in a separate `ItemTemplate` and `TemplateField` from the other buttons.  Is that causing an issue perhaps?  I'm not entirely familiar with these server controls so I'm not sure off-hand.

I should take a moment to point out that your code here is very fragile.  The problems you've been experiencing are the result of this.  You're referencing arrays by indexes manually, including the use of a "magic string" to reference them.  You might want to toss in some error checking for that.  You're also casting and later using objects without checking if they exist first.  `FindControl` can very easily return a `null` reference, such as when the control isn't found.

Throwing in tons of error checking is kind of part of the reality of using these web forms controls and their old data binding methods.  A lot of extra code, but that's how it goes with these controls and directly binding to weakly-typed DataSets and such.

Comment: i am debugging.. my error changed to object reference not set to an instance of an object on  btnDetails.CommandName = "Details"; line

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
        var ID = PersonGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
```

to

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var ID = PersonGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
```

i.e. extract the DataKeys only when the row is of DataRow and not for Header/Footer etc.

Comment: i recently did that.. and by doing, the error change to object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Comment: @Abid Ali, Could you please post the HTML back?