# npm soap -> ErrLog: Failed on each Compass instance

Tags: node.js, soap

I recently set up a soapClient using npm's soap, but in doing things in the same way that they worked for a previous SOAP call, it is not working now.

My soap call in Node looks like:

```
const url = "http://.....................?WSDL";

const service = 'ServiceName';

let args = {
  request: {
    a: 'some value',
    b: 0101,
    c: 1010,
    d: 'brand'
  }
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, soapClient) {
  if (err) console.log('Error @ creatClient')

  soapClient[service](args, function(err, result) {
  if(err) console.log('Error @ soap service: ', err)
  console.log('response: ', result) 
  })
})
```

The `request` inside `args` is nested in order to reflect the way that the original XML looks like. Without nesting the data, I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`error. But my current code (with nesting) gets me:

```
response: 
{ 
  ServiceName: { 
    ErrLog: 'Failed on each [App] instance. [App] http://..... got back error: [App] http://..... got back error: [App] http://.... got back error:',
    result: false 
  } 
}
```

The goal is to get a `true` on that `result` key. Any feedback on the errors is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `soapClient[service](args['request'], function(err, result) {`

Comment: your recommendation is the same as if I jut pass the flat args object: I then get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083100/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?rq=1

Comment: @JaimePericas try `JSON.stringify(args['request'])` let me know, I am waiting

Comment: if that still does not work try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args['request']))`

Comment: The error was due to a field that was said to be optional in the documentation but in fact was required. Thnx for all the feedback.